# Find and update with a single request

Tags: eve

Is there a way to combine `GET` and `PATCH` together for document(s)? My use case is, when I do a `GET` on a collection with `max_results` set or by using filters, I want it to change its state by modifying one of the fields.

This is for EVE, python rest framework based on Flask.

Comment: something equivalent to `db.collection.findOneAndUpdate()` in mongo shell.

Comment: I believe I can use event hooks but still if anyone has any better ideas, that'll be great. http://python-eve.org/features.html#event-hooks

Comment: You are right. I would bet on a `on_fetched_resource` database event hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found options - point is to use event based hooks and you can make it do anything you want.

I'll just post a link for my reference.
http://python-eve.org/features.html#event-hooks